# mySQL alter table on update, current timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

```
alter table `quote` 
modify column `timestamp` 
    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    NOT NULL
```

What's wrong with the above mysql query?

I am trying to change my timestamp column to default and update with the current timestamp.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL' at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `MODIFY COLUMN col_name` the syntax requires a `column_definition` which in turn requires a type.  Add the current type of this column (e.g. `DATETIME`) before `DEFAULT` to resolve the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much an answer as it is a tip. In MySQL workbench 6.3 community build, if you want to modify the column using the table edit screen, make certain the "Data Type:" for your timestamp column is for sure set to **TIMESTAMP** and then make **ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** the default value (on my screen, it is just below the "Data Type:").